# Mysql Procedure error,

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i am trying to create the following mysql procedure, but i am stuck for last two hours, and i have no clue what is wrong with it.

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists pos_finder;
    create procedure pos_finder()
     begin
     declare below, normal, normal_h, svalue, eid, above int default 0;
     declare bcounter, ncounter, acounter int default 0;
     declare done int default 0;
     declare userData cursor for select e.id, s.value, t.below_normal_h,
t.Normal_b, t.Normal_h, t.above_normal_l from k_employee as e, k_trackers_data as s, k_trackers_sub as t where e.id = 3 and s.user_id = e.id and t.id = s.sub_tracker_id;
     declare continue handler for not found set done = 1;
     open userData;
     fetch userData into eid, svalue, below, normal, normal_h, above;
     if svalue < below then
     set bcounter = bcounter + 1;
     else if svalue > normal then
     set ncounter = ncounter + 1;
     else if svalue > above then
     set acounter = acounter + 1;
     end if;
     close userData;
     end$$
```

Mysql says

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at
line 19
```

which is **close userData** line. i shifted line breaks here and there it always give error on this line only

Please someone can tell me where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elseif`, not `else[space]if`. With a space, you're opening a brand new `if` block. So there's two "dangling" if's by the time you reach the `close` call.

Comment: you saved my day :) i almost gave up on mysql and started working on logic in php.. thanks a ton :) :)